# Gitlab 8.7 repositories size differ backup-restore (6.9) from Import option (8.7)

Tags: git, repository, backup, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

So, I'm in the process of migrating my repositories to a new server:

Old Server:  -->      New Server
Gitlab 6.9  -->   Gitlab 8.7

So What I did was to create a backup following the documentation
after which :

1. installed 6.9 version in the new server so that I was able to restore the backup.
2. restore all my repositories to the new  server and updated to latest version 8.7.2

Once in the 8.7.2 version I found the import option and gave it a go with an specific repository and I was comparing the one that I restored from the backup to the one from the import and so my question is why is the big difference in sizes

- what is missing from the imported one?
- is it going to function alright?

Original one. I have not used it for nothing, why is not showing any commit? also the size is 46.43MB
[image: Original one]
This one,I started using today so I deleted some branches and added a new tag and so that's why they differ,its showing the commits but the size is 10.08MB what's wrong with it?

[image: imported one]

Comment: Considering that you have fewer branches then there's the possibility that the garbage collection kicked in and cleaned the reflog so you gained back some space.

Comment: @fuzzmz not really everything was the same the only thing was the commits reported as 0 and the mismatch on the size. Right now the team is using the one I imported(10.08MB one), lets hope everything works as intended...